# Database php scripting, insert data into table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am fairly new to php and for my database class we need to insert data using a php form. I am using MySQL workbench, MAMP, and phpmyadmin if that helps. My question is, how do I get the form to interact with the php script that are attatched below. How do I get the value in the Title box assigned to $value, rating to $value2, etc. These are two separate files in my server and when I go to the index and select my php script, it returns a 500 error, so it doesn't work at the moment.

I've made sure that the db name is correct as well as the user and password.
The image attached is my movie table with the column headers
[image]

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'movie_database');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3036');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}


$value = $_POST['title'];
$value2 = $_POST['rating'];
$value3 = $_POST['Runtime'];  
$value4 = $_POST['movie_rating'];
$value5 = $_POST['release_date'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, rating, Runtime, movie_rating, 
release_date) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3','$value4','$value5')";
echo "Inserted correctly!"
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

This just makes the text boxes:

```html
<form action="form1.php" method="post"/>
<p>Enter Movie Title: <input type="text" name="title"/></p> 
<p>Enter Movie Rating(G,PG,PG-13,R): <input type="text" name="rating"/></p> 
<p>Enter Movie Runtime in minutes: <input type="text" name="Runtime"/></p> 
<p>Enter IMDB Movie Rating(0-10.0): <input type="text" name="movie_rating"/></p> 
<p>Enter Movie Release date(YYYY-MM-DD): <input type="text" name="release_date"/></p>  
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Edit: Just found out that MAMP has an error log. Looking in the phperror log this shows up: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in E:\MAMP\MAMP\htdocs\forms.php:8
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in E:\MAMP\MAMP\htdocs\forms.php on line 8

Comment: Just a tip: with MAMP you can go to `/Applications/MAMP/logs` and check the `apache_error.log` and `php_error.log`. It looks like most likely your `$values` aren't being entered into the string properly

Comment: Didn't know MAMP had that, thanks. I found the following error in phperror log. PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' in E:\MAMP\MAMP\htdocs\forms.php on line 29

Comment: Well that helps - I've just spotted the syntax error - `echo "Inserted correctly!"` you're missing the closing `;`. Which is most likely causing your 500 error!

Comment: Fixed that and now this error shows: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in E:\MAMP\MAMP\htdocs\forms.php:8
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in E:\MAMP\MAMP\htdocs\forms.php on line 8

Comment: Which php version is installed?

Comment: @DestinatioN I am using version 7.1

Comment: PHP 7 removes the mysql extension because it was already deprecated in PHP 5. So you can use PHP 5 or mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: Did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer below - I've provided a simple mysqli example

Comment: I figured how to change the php version in MAMP to 5.5 and it works now! Except I get this error now: Could not connect: Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (0). And you addressed this is your answer, ill take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you had a syntax error with a missing `;` (which you've now fixed), but there is still two issues:

Your `DB_HOST` variable is not set properly, it should just be:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

You don't need the port number and with MAMP you most likely need to use the localhost IP: 127.0.0.1

Your second problem is the way you're creating the insert query, it should look like this when you're concatenating values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, rating, Runtime, movie_rating, release_date)
VALUES ('".$value."', '".$value2."', '".$value3."','".$value4."','".$value5."')";
```

In saying that `PHP MySQL` has been **deprecated since PHP 5.5.0**

So try using `PHP MySQLi` like below:

```
<?php
$databaseName = 'movie_database';
$databaseUser = 'root';
$databasePassword = 'root';
$databaseHost = '127.0.0.1';

$conn = new mysqli($databaseHost, $databaseUser, $databasePassword, $databasePassword);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Connected successfully";

// Note* This is basic sanitizing but you can be more careful with this
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rating']);
$value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Runtime']);
$value4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['movie_rating']);
$value5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['release_date']);

// Concatenate the $values into the string
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, rating, Runtime, movie_rating, release_date)
    VALUES ('".$value."', '".$value2."', '".$value3."','".$value4."','".$value5."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to 'stop' and 'start' the string again:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, rating, Runtime, movie_rating, 
release_date) VALUES ('".$value."', '".$value2."', '".$value3."','".$value4."','".$value5."')";
```

Because what you are doing right now is just inserting "$value" instead of the actual value behind that variable.

Answer (score -1):

you just forget the semicolon(;) after echo statement, hope this will help you.

```
$value = $_POST['title'];
$value2 = $_POST['rating'];
$value3 = $_POST['Runtime'];  
$value4 = $_POST['movie_rating'];
$value5 = $_POST['release_date'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, rating, Runtime, movie_rating,
release_date) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3','$value4','$value5')";
//forget ';' after echo
echo "Inserted correctly!";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```